# OpenGL features in view based application

Tags: opengl-es

Can we use OpenGles Features in a view based application?

I mean in a view-based application when one presses the button, the application should go to OpenGLes view and display the image processing application.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to know. If you write "view based" what do you mean by "view"? The general concept, like in MVC, or some specific widget class, or something completely different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [openGL features in view based application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388458/opengl-features-in-view-based-application)

Answer (score 0):

Given that vague of a question all I can do is point you to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html and hope for the best. More info might lend to better answers.