# openGL features in view based application

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Can we use OpenGles Features in a viewbased application on iphone??

i mean in view based application when i button pressed it will goes to OpenGLes view and displays the image processing application... please help me....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mix OpenglES with standard Cocoa widgets on an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057529/can-i-mix-opengles-with-standard-cocoa-widgets-on-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can freely mix OpenGL and UIKit code in one app. The only thing that identifies a view as being OpenGL-based in iOS is that its backing layer is an instance of `CAEAGLLayer`, i.e. you have to override `+layerClass` in your OpenGL view class and have it return `[CAEAGLLayer class]`.